# Активная ссылка

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста как сделать вот такую ссылку

```
       <a href='mes?id=<?=$myrow["id"]?>&hash=<?=$hash?>' >
```

активной при нажатии, hash передается методом GET.

Comment: опишите подробнее, что Вы имеете ввиду под "активной"? Здесь много контекстов, так что уточните

Comment: Вот у меня есть система сообщений, и мне нужно вот например есть два юзера с кем я общаюсь и вот ссылка передаваемая методом Get.Мне нужно что бы при выборе диалога конкретного ссылка была активной.изменила например цвет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну используйте css, :active псевдокласс